# Как вызвать исключение внутри CASE выражения?

Tags: sql, oracle, исключения, plsql, обработка-ошибок

Вот упрощённо то, что хочу сделать:

```
declare
    res int;
    function foo (x int) return int is
    begin
        return case x when between 1 and 99 then x
            else raise value_error end;
    end; 
begin 
    res := foo (100); 
end;
/
```

Но это поему-то не компилируется:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE_ERROR" when expecting one of the following:
> [длинный список, что компилятор ожидал]

Можно конечно добавить строкой выше `IF`, но так же проще написать.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` выражение (*expression*) после `THEN` ожидает выражение, которое может вернуть значение. Предложение `RAISE` им не является.

Создайте функцию, которая вызовет исключение:

```
create or replace function raiseErr (errm varchar2, errn int:=20000) return int is
begin 
    raise_application_error (-errn, errm); 
end;
/
```

Заметьте, отсутствие `return` в реализции, эта функция только "обещает" вернуть, но никогда ничего не вернёт.

Так будет работать:

```
declare
    res int;
    function foo (x int) return int is
    begin
        return case when x between 1 and 99 then x
            else raiseErr ('Illegal value '||x) end;
    end; 
begin 
    res := foo (100); 
end;
/
```

> Error report -
> ORA-20000: Illegal value 100